# Trying to query sqlight, query method query keeps causing a exception

Tags: android

I have a table with these columns:

```
id, exchange, name
```

I create a record following values

```
 na, "ted1", "ted1-curA"
```

I then query it, where have is `exchange=ted1`.

```
 database.query(true, "cur", null, null
            , null, "name","exchange=name1", null, null);
```

which throws a exception saying `no such column name1`

Test code is

```
 void test()
 {
     // put name into exchange    
     createCur("name1", "ted1-curA");

     try {
         // get record we just added       
         database.query(true, "cur", null, null, null, "name", "exchange=name1", null, null);
     } catch( Exception e)
     {
         ct++;
     }
}

public long createCur(String exchange, String name) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("exchange", exchange);
    values.put("name", name);

    long rt=database.insert("cur", null, values);
    return rt;
}
}
```

Comment: name1 should be single quoted like `"exchange='name1'"`

Answer (score 0):

name1 should be in single quoted like "exchange='name1'"

best way to building dataBases is using constants in a seperated class
please create a constant class and put all of your db constants in there like this:

```
public static final String DATA_BASE_NAME = "appStructure.db";
public static final int DATA_BASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Data_Table";
public static final String COLUMN_IDS = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "Titles";
public static final String COLUMN_CONTENT = "Contents";
public static final String COLUMN_IMAGE = "Images";
public static final String COLUMN_LOCATION = "Location";

public static final String CREATE_DB_TABLE_COMMAND = "CREATE TABLE 
"+TABLE_NAME+"( "+COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
"+COLUMN_TITLE+" TEXT, "+COLUMN_CONTENT+" TEXT, "+COLUMN_IMAGE+" BLOB, 
"+COLUMN_LOCATION+" TEXT"+");";
```

and use them in your project easily.